# Liferay iframe java script document unavaible

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, liferay

I have project based on liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5. On my page I want to have iframe with dynamic height.

Right now I do have my iframe like this:

```
   <iframe id="1231-iframe" nam="iframe-name" src="http://localhost:123/ca-clickableDummy/test.html"
```

page content (on payara41) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 600px;background-color: #3c763d"> sadas</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but if I want to do anything with iframe content I`m receive bug:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

No matter what I`m doing from jquery/js I cannot access this property, what blocks me.

Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at MDN?

Comment: I cannot find anything useful :( Or I`m to dummy for this.

Comment: maybe is a problem of cross domain. For security reasons, this simple way of cross iframe communication was disabled years ago by all browser vendors.